# r select multiple rows for variables based on maximum and minimum values of one column

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below;

[image]

I would like to select maximum and minimum 'probability' value in the 'years' 2017. And, whichever topic has the maximum and minimum probability value, all instances of those topics must be gathered in another data frame like below;

[image]

(in the above example topic V16 has the minimum probability of all in 2017 and V30 has the maximum probability)

Comment: Please add [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  If we need to get the rows of 'topic' where the 'probability' is `max/min` only for 'years' 2017, then

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(topics %in% topics[probability == max(probability) & years == 2017]| 
           topics %in% topics[probability == min(probability) & years == 2017])
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups: years [2]
#   years topics probability
#   <int> <chr>        <dbl>
#1  2016 V10         0.0553
#2  2016 V15         0.0164
#3  2017 V30         0.0714
#4  2017 V16         0.0130
```

---

Or use `slice`

```
df1 %>%
   slice(c(which(topics %in% topics[probability == max(probability) & years == 2017]),
       which(topics %in% topics[probability == min(probability) & years == 2017])))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   years topics probability
#   <int> <chr>        <dbl>
#1  2016 V30         0.0219
#2  2017 V30         0.0714
#3  2016 V16         0.0300
#4  2017 V16         0.0130
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df1, topics %in% subset(df1, years == 2017 & 
            probability %in% range(probability), select = "topics")[[1]])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(years = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L
), topics = c("V1", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", 
"V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V2", "V20", "V21", "V22", "V23", 
"V24", "V25", "V26", "V27", "V28", "V29", "V3", "V30", "V4", 
"V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V1", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", 
"V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V2", "V20", "V21", 
"V22", "V23", "V24", "V25", "V26", "V27", "V28", "V29", "V3", 
"V30", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9"), probability = c(0.045, 
0.0553, 0.03038, 0.0454189, 0.0347, 0.0278, 0.0164, 0.030016, 
0.0205, 0.0212, 0.0434, 0.0506, 0.0376, 0.019, 0.04, 0.033, 0.019, 
0.0499, 0.0204, 0.049, 0.02044, 0.03, 0.0207, 0.0219, 0.035, 
0.019, 0.044, 0.037, 0.0327, 0.046, 0.021, 0.03015, 0.028, 0.0299, 
0.015, 0.0439, 0.0378, 0.013, 0.0241, 0.0454, 0.0226, 0.0207, 
0.0258, 0.0237, 0.063, 0.027, 0.018, 0.058, 0.0255, 0.0172, 0.0576, 
0.0706, 0.035, 0.0714, 0.0266, 0.0228, 0.0183, 0.0265, 0.0376, 
0.0409)), .Names = c("years", "topics", "probability"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
a=setDT(df)[years==2017,topics[c(which.min(probability),which.max(probability))],by=years]
subset(df,topics%in%a$V1)
```

in base r, you can do something like:

```
a=aggregate(probability~years,subset(df,years==2017),function(x)c(which.max(x),which.min(x)))
subset(df,topics%in%topics[c(a$probability)])
```